# RDCOMClient - Set Vertical Range Values

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I am trying to write values into a vertical `Range` using the `RDCOMClient` library. Since the `RDCOMClient` allows you to write code very similar to VBA, I've been looking for ways to do this in VBA and then translate to R.

The base R code to create the excel is:

```
app <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
app[['Visible']] <- TRUE

workbook <- app$WorkBooks()$Open(path)
sheet <- workbook$Worksheets(sheet_name)
sheet$Activate()
```

If my `Range` was **horizontal** then I could simply write it as:

- **VBA**

  ```
  Range("A1:C1").Value = Array(1,2,3)
  ```
- **R**

  ```
  range <- sheet$Range('A1:C1')
  range[['Value']] <- c(1,2,3)
  ```

Since the `Range` is **vertical** the code is:

- **VBA**

  ```
  Range("A1:A3").Value = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3))
  ```
- **R**

  ```
  range <- sheet$Range('A1:A3')
  range[['Value']] <- app$Transpose(c(1,2,3))
  ```

The problem is that the R "translation" for the **vertical case does not work**.

Printing the `range[['Value']]` in the console shows:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[1]][[3]]
NULL
```

And the `app$Transpose(c(1,2,3))` shows:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3
```

Why is it not setting the values correctly? What is the correct way to do this?

I also tried using a matrix:

```
range[['Value']] <- matrix(nrow = 3, c(1,2,3))
```

But it gives an error:

```
Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object
```

I also tried setting the `range[['Value']][[1]]` directly with no success.

Comment: Does not matter if print before or after the result is the same. I know they do the same, but the way you write the code is a bit different, that's why I said very similar. @Parfait

Comment: Print console and excel. The print output is the same before and after assign (no value). The excel stays blank with no values.

Comment: You can run the code, it is all there. Just change the paths.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. I worked around it by something like `values <- 1:3; rng <- sheet$Range("A3:A5"); for (i in 1:rng$Cells()$Count()) { cell <- rng$Cells(i);  cell[["Value"]] <- values[i] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put vertical `1:7` in the cells `B3` to `B9`:

```
r= sheet$Range("B3:B9")
r[["Value"]] <- asCOMArray(matrix(1:7, 7, 1))
```